# Making a sitemap for a site with multiple subdomains

Tags: seo, subdomain, xml-sitemap

I currently own a site that has 20+ different subdomains. (like foo.google.com and subdomain.google.com) and the XML sitemap generators that i try to use dont go into those sites will i have to do it by hand or is there one that does it for me out there. Thanks in advance

Comment: Creating a sitemap is completely unnecessary unless you have pages that cannot be crawled using links on your site such as behind a paywall or login. There is no advantage to having a sitemap. Other than that, you will need one for each sub-domain and the parent site and each would exist on each site. In other words, no URLs for sub-domains can exist in the sitemap on the parent domain or another sub-domain. Personally, unless your domain cannot be crawled entirely, I would not bother. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc so why does google want me to upload one for the site. will it decrease rank at all?

Comment: Sitemaps have nothing to do with rank. As well, sitemaps are only used by Google to audit the ability to crawl a site. Nothing more, unless like I mentioned before, you have pages that are behind a paywall or login. Google talks about creating a sitemap, however, never says you need one.

Comment: Very true. But I once almost lost an account because some piranha tried to convince the client that the lack of sitemaps was causing him irreparable harm SEO-wise. The piranha even showed the client a screenshot of the Google Webmaster Tools page about sitemaps to try to make me look negligent. So now I use them -- but only to give the piranhas one less piece of potential ammunition.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a sitemap generator, just enter the URL to the subdomain in the box, and then place the resulting sitemap in the root of that subdomain.